Platform Term 7.e.i.1 - Timely response to our requests
Platform Term 7.e.i.1 - Timely response to our requests
We haven’t received a response to recent requests for information that we require in order to conduct a review of your app. As a result, your app is in violation of Platform Term 7.e.i.1.
I need to How I can Fix the issues.

did you manage to fix this?

Hi @Dipak any update here? Because I got sam issue and they are not mentioned like how many days they will keep in this violation (Platform Term 7.e.i.1 - Timely response to our requests)
